# how to make json request in haskell using wreq?

Tags: python, json, haskell

I have a server which accepts json requests and they work fine with python client. I am trying to do the same thing in haskell.

For instance my python client has following code

```
conn = JSONRPCProxy("XXX.XX.XX.XX", 5050, "2.0", 120)
print conn.request('show_attrs', [{"shortcode":"CODEWORD1","fx":'CD2'}, ["?queryattr", "queryname"]]);
```

I want to send out the same query using haskell and get json back as result. Not worried about json parsing as of now!

I tried Network.Wreq and it kinda works but always gives no response

```
data MyPriceRequest = MyRequestRequest { method::String,id::Int} deriving (Show,Generic)

instance ToJSON MyPriceRequest
r <- post "http://IP.IP.IP.IP:port/" (toJSON (MyRequestRequest  "codeword" [""] 1))

*** Exception: NoResponseDataReceived
```

I get exception but same code works with python

In python it works with...

```
conn = JSONRPCProxy("IP.IP.IP.IP", port, "2.0", 120)
print conn.request('codeword', []);
```

Comment: I would suggest to use wreq which is a more modern and suitalble library for this: http://www.serpentine.com/wreq/

Comment: and you certainly do not need json-rpc ;)

Comment: doesn't work...this same python request reports error in haskell...

Comment: [{"u1":["a1"], "bt":["C"], "p":["1"], "b2":["0.25"], "dd":["5m"],"cur":["ud"],"cs":["10"]}, ["?shortcode_info", "?okpr"]]

Comment: post "http://ipaddress:port/" [{"u1":["a1"], "bt":["C"], "p":["1"], "b2":["0.25"], "dd":["5m"],"cur":["ud"],"cs":["10"]}, ["?shortcode_info", "?okpr"]]  gives errro

Comment: <interactive>:13:9: parse error on input ‘{’

Comment: the exact same request goes through with python where i specify the method name to call, here its a bit confusion coz even json is giving error

Comment: Can anyone post a proper code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a working example doing a `POST` query on `httpbin.org`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Network.Wreq
import Control.Lens
import Data.Aeson.Lens
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.Aeson

main = do
    r <- post "http://httpbin.org/post" (toJSON (T.unpack "123"))

    let datas = r ^. responseBody . key "data" . _String
        ua    = r ^. responseBody . key "headers" . key "User-Agent" . _String

    (putStrLn . T.unpack) datas
    (putStrLn . T.unpack) ua
```

It should print something like:

```
"123"
haskell wreq-0.3.0.1
```

I tried it with URLs of the form `http://127.0.0.1:80` and it gave the same result.

Have you tried to use `curl` in your shell to see if it exhibits the same behavior ?
Is it possible that the server answers only if some header fields are present or set at a specific value ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Actually I realized yesterday that python client was using netstrings. The server just expects netstrings, so trying to understand how the server works. On python side I used the library jsonrpc_ns, which works fine